# Sending MMS via MonkeyRunner on Android throws Java exception

Tags: mms, monkeyrunner

I need to send MMS by writing a MonkeyRunner script. My script is as below  and it throws an exception. Can anyone please help? I am interested in writing scripts using intents and not using co-ordinates method:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice, MonkeyRunner, MonkeyImage
device= MonkeyDevice
for i in range(5):
device =MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(8)
if device != None:
print "Device found..."
break;
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG"); 
sendIntent.putExtra("999999", toText); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MMS");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", textMessage); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
device.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

> 130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
>       130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Synta
>       xError: ("mismatched input 'sendIntent' expecting NEWLINE", ('C:\Users\halappa\Work\MMBU\EOS2\ES2\Samsung\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\adt-bundle
>       -windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\mms.py', 9, 7, 'Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG"); \n'))
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at org.python.core.ParserFacade.fixParseError(ParserFacade.java:94)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parse(ParserFacade.java:143)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at org.python.core.Py.compile_flags(Py.java:1644)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at org.python.core.**builtin**.execfile_flags(**builtin**.java:530)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:156)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.run(ScriptRunner.java:116)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:77)
>   130508 12:37:35.663:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]
>       at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:18
>       9)

Comment: It seems you are mixing Python and Java in the same source, won't work

Comment: Yes, monkey runner is essentially python+java i.e Jython.so i would assume it works?can anyone please let me know if there is any other way to automate MMS sending using monkey runner?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what Jython is, read http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#What_is_Jython.3F

Comment: Good question, and, read dtmilano's comment. I have successfully launched SMS and MMS applications on several android devices using the same code via monkeyrunner programatically with a package/application name and intent wthout using touch methods. However, sending the message requires a touch to the send button and knowing the send button's coordinates. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to send an SMS or an MMS programatically in a monkeyrunner script using a device shell command to use activity manager to start an activity with an intent built with the start parameters

```
device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t vnd.android-dir/mms-sms -e address \'number or adderess goes here\' -e subject \'subject goes here\' -e sms_body \'message body goes here\'")
```

This will launch the default SMS or MMS application with the number/address, subject and message as supplied in the intent extras.

If you don't have a default SMS/MMS messaging application and there are more than one on the device, you will need to choose one of the several in a popup dialog.

Whether you send an SMS or MMS seems to depend on whether there is a subject extra included. On my devices, the message is an SMS if there is no subject extra and is an MMS if there is a subject extra.

The above will only launch the SMS/MMS application with the supplied address and message and, if also supplied, the subject. However, it won't send the message. I've always had to add a touch to the send button with its x, y coordinates to get the message to send.

```
device.touch(x coordinate here, y coordinate here, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

There are three extras for the intent, an address, a subject and a sms_body. I've tried using monkeyrunner with the direct intent creation and not the `am start` command from the device shell but I've never successfully extras into the intent with that approach whereas the code above works. The other direct intent creation works for me only when the intent doesn't need extras.

If you need the x, y coordinates of the send button, you can get them for more recent devices by turning on "Pointer location" in the device's developer options. The device's screen will then have a very narrow translucent ribbon at the top of the screen with information about your screen touches, blue crosshairs marking a current touch location and a blue track/trail from any touch motion. The ribbon at the top indicates location, velocity of motion and other data. For touch coordinates, launch the application and touch the screen where the send button is to find its coordinates.

Coordinates are ALWAYS relative to the uppermost left corner of the current device orientation. That means if you rotate the device from portrait to landscape, the coordinates will be relative to whatever corner becomes the uppermost left corner in the new orientation even if the application doesn't rearrange itself for the new orientation.

Also, in my scripts, I dismiss the soft keyboard with a programatic BACK button just before the touch for the send button.

```
device.press('KEYCODE_BACK', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

I've found that whether the soft keyboard is shown or not is not very predictable, so, before dismissing the soft keyboard, I include a test for whether it is showing or not using a method shown here in another stack overflow answer:

[How to Determine Whether Soft Keyboard Is Shown on Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903907/how-to-determine-whether-softkeyboard-is-shown-on-the-screen-while-using-monke/19686510#19686510)

Enjoy!